# How to install missing kernel modules? Is it possible?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, vpn, strongswan

My machine:

- An Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS on a PINE64 with an ARM 64-bit processor (Linux pine64 3.10.105-0-pine64-longsleep #3 SMP PREEMPT Sat Mar 11 16:05:53 CET 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux)

---

My goal is to get my PINE64 worked as a VPN server with L2TP/IPsec protocol by strongSwan.

Now, I have a problem that my PINE64 doesn't have required kernel modules for strongSwan listed here: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/KernelModules

I tried `sudo modprobe MODULE_NAME` and only knew that my PINE64 had no such module in directory `/lib/modules/3.10.105-0-pine64-longsleep`.

---

Here, My questions are:

- Is there any way to install these missing modules to my PINE64?
- If exists, how?
- Do you have any better workaround to make a VPN server on my PINE64?
- Any suggestion?

Not only specific answers for PINE64 but also general answers for Linux are appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu's default kernel has all the required modules. Where did you get the PINE64-specific kernel? What's the output of the configuration check script on that wiki page?

Comment: @Gilles I got the specific kernel for PINE64 from the official wiki page of PINE64: http://wiki.pine64.org/index.php/Main_Page#Curated_Pine_A64_.28A64.2B.29_OS_Images. And the result of the check.sh only showed that the directory /boot/config-uname` was missing and I didn't find any file which had a name like config-`uname within /boot directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to build them your self from source. A similar question was asked here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module